# Blazor Client (webassembly) Facebook or Google login

Tags: authentication, authorization, facebook-login, blazor, google-signin

I know it isn't a specific issue, but can you give me any guideline how to create Facebook or Google login for Blazor Client (Webassembly) app?
I emphasize Client (so not Server!) because it is exist and working well.

Or just tell me that it is possible? And need I use the server (asp.net core web api) or the client would be enough itself?

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: The client is enough, you need to customize the login page and add more than one authentication provider in your DI. I don't test it yet but it's possible with some customization. Maybe you also have to override the AuthenticationStateProvider.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-authentication-user-interface

Answer (score 1):

I've found docs on MS page regarding [3rd login providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-for-hosted-apps-and-third-party-login-providers). And this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) describes OIDC auth process. The Blazor wasm authentication uses *oidc-client.js* library, which is capable of oauth2 and oidc. Therefore, it is possible and client should be enough(see the quote below).

> The server hosting the app doesn't play a role.

However, I haven't found any examples of this.

Comment: I created a new client app and I was following the articles. Can you tell me how to set up properly for facebook?

Startup: https://prnt.sc/sfa0vc
appsettings.json: https://prnt.sc/sfa1sw
After clicking on login: https://prnt.sc/sfa29z

What is going wrong? (The FB app is set up properly, I can use it from a Server app)

Comment: Basically the https://localhost:44319/authentication/login (I assume it should do the authentication automatically inside the framework) redirects to the /login-failed page